# SetEvent not releasing WaitForSingleObject in qthread

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, events, qthread

Im not familiar with winApi. my requirement is to monitor the changes in the directory in a particular path.so i tried my code like  this.

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QReadWriteLock>
#include <QDebug>

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winbase.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#endif // Q_OS_WIN

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
#include <unistd.h>
#endif // Q_OS_LINUX




class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QReadWriteLock lock;
    bool running;
    LPCWSTR m_path;
    HANDLE myEvent;



public slots:
    void loop() {
        qDebug() << "entering the loop";
        bool _running;
        forever {

            lock.lockForRead();
            _running = running;
            lock.unlock();

            if (!_running) return;

            qDebug() << "loop iteration";

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
            OVERLAPPED overlapped;
            memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(overlapped));
            overlapped.hEvent = myEvent;
            myEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
            DWORD dwWaitResult  = WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE);

            switch (dwWaitResult)
             {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:

                qDebug()<<"Success";
                break;

            case WAIT_FAILED:
                //break;
            case WAIT_ABANDONED:

                 qDebug()<<"nWait failed.";
                break;
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
//                consoleprintf(L"\r\nWait Timed out: %d", waitTime);
                qDebug()<<"nWait Timed out.";
                break;
            default:
                qDebug()<<"Something else";
                break;
            }


#endif // Q_OS_WIN

    }
    qDebug()<<"Closing the loop ends..";
}

void closeLoop()
{

    WINBOOL state = SetEvent(myEvent);
    CloseHandle(myEvent);
     qDebug()<<"Releasing the close loop:"<<state;
}

private:


    };

class DirControll {
public:
    DirControll(const QString &apath) : m_currentPath(apath)
    {
        LPCWSTR path ;
        path = reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(m_currentPath.utf16());
        myWorker.m_path = path;
        myWorker.running = true;
        myWorker.connect(&myThread, SIGNAL(started()), &myWorker, SLOT(loop()));
        myWorker.moveToThread(&myThread);
        myThread.start();
    }
~Controller() {
    CloseController();

    //myThread.wait();
    //myThread.exit();
    //myThread.terminate();
}

void CloseDirControll()
{
    // Safely close threads
    myWorker.closeLoop();
    myWorker.lock.lockForWrite();
    myWorker.running = false;
    myWorker.lock.unlock();

    myThread.quit();
    qDebug()<<"the thread still runnign:"<<myThread.isRunning();
}
```

private:
    QThread myThread;
    Worker myWorker;
    QString m_currentPath;
};

but im unable to close the thread on calling CloseDirControll() -> closeLoop().WaitForSingleObject is not unblocking my thread to close. SetEvent(myEvent) is not releasing my WaitForSingleObject and i not get the thread loop closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced your myEvent initialization:

```
OVERLAPPED overlapped;
memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(overlapped));

// Here you assign myEvent - which is not yet initialized
overlapped.hEvent = myEvent;

myEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
// Above line 'overlapped.hEvent = myEvent;' should be here

DWORD dwWaitResult  = WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably mistyped in this 3 lines.

```
overlapped.hEvent = myEvent;
myEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
DWORD dwWaitResult  = WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE);
```

You should swap lines 2 and 1.

Comment: i dont knw hw to accept two answers .but i thanked you a lot .